# JavaScript regular expression 5-5000

Tags: javascript, regex

I know that this:

```
var regStartMoney = /[1-5][0-9][0-9][0-9]/;
```

allows you to enter from 1-5999.

how do I do it for a range of 5-5000?

Comment: The regex you've shown works for 1000-5999, not 1.

Comment: Why does it have to be a regular expression? Can you not convert the input to a numeric value and then check if it's within 5-5000?

Comment: Why do you want to use RegExp for a simple range checking? Could you just check it?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var regStartMoney = /^0*(?:[5-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]?|[1-4][0-9][0-9][0-9]|5000)$/;
```

Comment: I'd really not use [0-9] use \d makes it more readable - the 1-9 etc ranges are fine.

Comment: That's what I did too.  Karma's a B'  :)

Answer (score 1):

Regex misuse! Just do it the sane way:

```
var int = parseInt(input,10);
if (isNan(input)) {
    alert('Please enter a number.');
} else if (input != int) {
    alert('Decimals are not allowed.');
} else if (!(int >= 5 && int <= 5000)) {
    alert('Your number must be between 5 and 5000 (inclusive).');
} else {
    alert('Your number is valid!');
}
```

Comment: Sanity is not a requirement of the problem domain :)

Comment: @David Ok… Then why not try uploading the text to a server, which validates it using some program-y-thing downloaded from the "internet" onto Win 95, which gets sent back to the client, where JS ships it over to a different server where it gets printed out, then photographed by a low-res camera against a wooden table, before the result gets, finally sent back to JS in a .doc format… I think there's a jQuery plugin for that.

Comment: I had that client once 8^O

Comment: @David The only problem is that if you implement it you'd have to give credit to http://clientsfromhell.net in the already-overly-bloated footer… otherwise I'd be all for it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
var money = parseInt(input);
var test = Math.min(Math.max(money, 5), 5000);

if(money !== test) //
```

Comment: Because `money` is presumably a string, also, you're returning `money`, limited to the range 1-5000 - not at all what the OP is asking.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Would you say that the current answer fixes those issues, or am I still misunderstanding something?

Comment: Sure. Down-vote retracted. But wouldn't `if (money >= 5 && money <= 5000)` be much clearer? I don't like to have to think very hard when reading code.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart An unfortunate bi-product of starting in a complete different mindset. I'd update it but then it would really just be your answer with my name under it.

Answer (score 0):

You should really convert to a number and compare.  But that wasn't your question so here's your answer:

```
var regStartMoney = /^0*([5-9]|([1-9]\d{0,2})|([1-4]\d{3})|(50{3}))$/;
```

Here's a test script:

```
<script>
function checkMoney() {
  var money=document.getElementById("money").value;
  if (money.match(/^0*([5-9]|([1-9]\d{0,2})|([1-4]\d{3})|(50{3}))$/)) {
    alert(money+" is between 5-5000");
  } else {
    alert(money+" is not between 5-5000");
  }
}
</script>
<input id="money"/></br>
<input type="submit" onClick="checkMoney();"/><br/>
```

Test on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kQ3TD/20/)

Comment: I tested with `000`. The output was `000 is between 5-5000`.

Comment: err, is 000 valid? hmmm...  fixed anyway ;)